# pass nested classes of a specific class as an argument in java/android

Tags: java, android, function, generics

I have a `class M`, inside the class I have three nested classes namely `Class A, Class B, Class c`.

I need to pass any of the nested class (A/B/C) objects to a method namely `doSomething(***class A/B/C object***)`.

So my question is how to pass different objects of nested classes of `Class M` to a method outside `class M`?
Should I use generic class? if yes, Can you help me with the parameter?

**CLARIFICATION :**

I want a single method where instances of `M.A,M.B,M.C` can be passed as argument and method has to be outside `M`.

**More Clarification**

Let me tell you what I'm trying to achieve through the code.

I have a `class M` which in turn have 3 nested classes - `A, B, C`.
I create objects/instances of A, B, C by

```
M.A a = (new M()).new A();
M.B b = (new M()).new B();
M.C c = (new M()).new C();
```

Now to manipulate on values stored by A,B,C I have a function `doSomething()`.
I want to pass `a,b,c` to `doSomething()` at different times like

```
`doSomething(a);`
`doSomething(b);`
`doSomething(c);`
```

What I meant by the question is, how to declare function `doSomething()` such that I can pass a, b, c ?

In real project, nested classes are around 20 and I dont want to write same functionality of `doSomething()` again and again for operating on these instances of nested classes.

And `dosomething()` is outside of `class M`.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I need to pass any of the nested class (A/B/C) objects to a method namely doSomething(***class A/B/C object***)."? Do you want a single method that can be passed either A, B or C or do you want three different methods? Also, do these methods have to be inside `M` or outside `M`?

Comment: @CKing I want a single method where A,B,C can be passed and method has to outside M. Sorry for the confusion. I will update the question.

Comment: You need to give us ad much information as possible. You still haven't mentioned whether you want to pass an instance of A, B, C to the method or a Class argument to the method.

Comment: @CKing forgive me for that, I want to pass an instance of A or B or C as an argument to a method outside M. Classes A,B,C are nested classes of M.

Answer (score 1):

```
class M {    
    static class A implements I {
        public void whatever(){}
    }
    static class B implements I {
        public void whatever(){}
    }
    static class C implements I {
        public void whatever(){}
    }
    interface I {
        void whatever();
    }
}

class C {
    void doSomething(Class<I> clazz){}

    void doSomething(I i){}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        doSomething(M.A.class);
        doSomething(new M.B());
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass nested class object as an argument like doSomething(M.A a), just like we pass integer object like doSomething(int i)

Comment: Like `void doSomething(Class<I> clazz)` and then `doSomething(M.A.class)`?

Comment: Like that. Can you please tell me how to declare function 'doSomething()' and how to  pass the object as argument ?

Comment: That's contradictory to what you answered to @CKing. Anyway, I edited my answer, so now in class C you have two methods: one that receives a Class of type `I` and another that receives an instance of type `I`.

Comment: pardon me if I'm wrong, is it wrong to use object and instance interchangeably ?

Comment: Is this a prank? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No no, its not a prank. I'm working on a project and now stuck at this point for 4 hours.

Comment: In a class say M, I have 3 other classes - nested classes A, B, C.


I instantiate A  by `M.A  a = (new M()).new A;`


Now I need to pass it in a function like `doSomething(a)`

In this same way I need to pass objects/instances of `M.B` and `M.C`

the functionality of `doSomething()` is same, So I'm searching for a option to pass instances of `M.A`, `M.B`, `M.C` to the same function - `doSomething()`

Comment: Then the solution I wrote should work for you. You must make your nested classes inherit from one single interface and use it as an argument on your `doSomething` method.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. If this solved your problem, could you please set it as the correct answer? Thanks.

Comment: Actually your answer didn't help me. But thanks for the effort +1.